# CLASSPATH in crontab

Tags: java, cron

I am having trouble getting my Java program to run from `cron`.  I am able to recreate the problem, using a simple example, as explained below:

In the file `/path/to/javaenv.txt` I define my `CLASSPATH` variable as follows:

```
export CLASSPATH=\
"/path/to/dir1":\
"/path/to/dir2":\
"/path/to/dirn":\
"/path/to/jar1":\
"/path/to/jar2":\
"/path/to/jarn"
```

From the command line I am able to execute the Java program quite easily by doing something like this:

```
source "/path/to/javaenv.txt" && java pkgName.ClassName cmd-line-params > /tmp/test-$(date +%s).txt 2>&1
```

However, the job does not get executed from `cron`, eventhough my `crontab` has the following entry:

```
* * * * * source "/path/to/javaenv.txt" && java pkgName.ClassName cmd-line-params > /tmp/test-$(date +%s).txt 2>&1
```

Comment: `source` isn't an executable, it is built-in to a shell.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you package your command into a script, test it, and call that script from cron. Something like `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "/path/to/javaenv.txt" && java pkgName.ClassName cmd-line-params > /tmp/test-$(date +%s).txt 2>&1
```